# How to implement security for a group within an application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am developing an API with Identity for security, The app will have groups/pages (Entity) and each entity will have a Super Admin, Admin and other roles. For overall app roles implementing security is straight forward, but how do I implement security for the groups? I have code that checks the users role as follows

**The Repository Class **

```
public class UserEntityRoleRepository : RepositoryBase<UserEntityRole>, IUserEntityRoleRepository
    {
        public UserEntityRoleRepository(ARMASDataContext aRMASDataContext) : base(aRMASDataContext)
        {
        }

        public async Task<bool> isEntitySuperAdmin(string entityId, string userId) 
        {
            var entityRole = await this.ARMASDataContext.EntityRoles.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Name == "Entity Super Admin");

            return await this.hasRequiredRole(entityRole.Id, entityId, userId);
        }

        public async Task<bool> isEntityAdmin(string entityId, string userId)
        {
            var entityRole = await this.ARMASDataContext.EntityRoles.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Name == "Entity Admin");

            return await this.hasRequiredRole(entityRole.Id, entityId, userId);
        }

        public async Task<bool> isEntityHROfficer(string entityId, string userId)
        {
            var entityRole = await this.ARMASDataContext.EntityRoles.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Name == "Entity HR Officer");

            return await this.hasRequiredRole(entityRole.Id, entityId, userId);
        }

        public async Task<bool> isEntityAccountant(string entityId, string userId)
        {
            var entityRole = await this.ARMASDataContext.EntityRoles.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Name == "Entity Accounts");

            return await this.hasRequiredRole(entityRole.Id, entityId, userId);
        }

        public async Task<bool> isEntityAuditor(string entityId, string userId)
        {
            var entityRole = await this.ARMASDataContext.EntityRoles.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Name == "Entity Auditor");

            return await this.hasRequiredRole(entityRole.Id, entityId, userId);
        }

        public async Task<bool> isEntityConsultant(string entityId, string userId)
        {
            var entityRole = await this.ARMASDataContext.EntityRoles.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Name == "Entity Consultant");

            return await this.hasRequiredRole(entityRole.Id, entityId, userId);
        }

        private async Task<bool> hasRequiredRole(string entityRoleId, string entityId, string userId)
        {
            /*The following code is used to check if the provided EntityRoleId maps to row with User's 
            Id and Entity's Id  in UserEntity table through middle table UserEntityRole
            */

            return await this.ARMASDataContext.UserEntityRoles.Where(c => c.EntityRoleId == entityRoleId)
                                                                                .Include(c => c.UserEntity)
                                                                                .Where(c => c.UserEntity.UserId == userId && c.UserEntity.EntityId == entityId)
                                                                                .Select(c => new { c.Id })
                                                                                .AsQueryable().CountAsync() > 0;

        }
    }
```

**The Service Class **

```
public class EntityService : IEntityService
    {
        .........

        public async Task<bool> TestEntityRoleCheckSuperAdmin(string entityId, string userId) 
        {
            return await _unitOfWork.UserEntityRole.isEntitySuperAdmin(entityId, userId);
        }

        public async Task<bool> TestEntityRoleCheckAdmin(string entityId, string userId)
        {
            return await _unitOfWork.UserEntityRole.isEntityAdmin(entityId, userId);
        }

        ........
    }
```

and the Controller

```
public class EntityController : ControllerBase
    {
        ............

        // POST api/<EntityController>
        [Authorize]
        [HttpPost("RoleTestSuperAdmin")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<string>> RoleTestSuperAdmin()
        {
            string userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier); // will give the user's userId
            string entityId = "e90fb3ab-347d-450f-ab9b-0cb187a22ae1";

           var hasRole = await _entityService.TestEntityRoleCheckSuperAdmin(entityId, userId);

            if (hasRole)
            {
                string message = "User Has the required role";
                
                var result = new OkObjectResult(new {message});
                return result;
            }

            return Unauthorized();
        }


        [Authorize]
        [HttpPost("RoleTestAdmin")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> RoleTestAdmin()
        {
            string userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier); // will give the user's userId
            string entityId = "e90fb3ab-347d-450f-ab9b-0cb187a22ae1";

            var hasRole = await _entityService.TestEntityRoleAdmin(entityId, userId);

            if (hasRole)
            {
                return Ok(StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status200OK, new Response { Status = "Success", Message = "The account has The Requested Role" }));
            }

            return Unauthorized();

        }

       ........
    }
```

The above code works perfectly fine, but is there a way to implement that as a policy with parameters for UserId and EntityId?

Comment: Identity is based mainly on claims-based authorization. So if you want to use more data for authorizing, just add more claims for users. Identity has api to persist user's claims at the time logging-in (after succeeded).

Answer (score 0):

You could write custom policy handlers and implement Policy-based authorization in your application.

For example:

Create a CustomUserEntityRoleClaim.cs file: it could use to transfer the role name.

```
public class CustomUserEntityRoleClaim: IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public string RoleName { get; }
    public CustomUserEntityRoleClaim(string roleName)
    {
        RoleName = roleName;
    }
}
```

Create a CustomUserEntityRoleHandler: In this handler you could call your UserEntityRoleRepository service and check user's role.

```
public class CustomUserEntityRoleHandler : AuthorizationHandler<CustomUserEntityRoleClaim>
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    public CustomUserEntityRoleHandler(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, CustomUserEntityRoleClaim requirement)
    {
        if (context.User == null || !context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            context.Fail();
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        //get current user id
        var userid = _context.ApplicationUsers.Where(c=>c.UserName ==  context.User.Identity.Name).FirstOrDefault().Id;
        //according to the role name to find the role id.
        var roleid = _context.EntityRoles.Where(c=>c.EntityRoleName== requirement.RoleName).Select(c=>c.EntityRoleId).FirstOrDefault();
        var validRole = false;

        //According to the userid and roleid to query the UserEntityRoles table, then based on the result to verify whether the user has the special roles.
        var result = _context.UserEntityRoles.Where(c => c.UserId == userid && c.EntityRoleId == roleid).ToList();

        if (result.Count>0)
        {
            validRole = true;
        } 

        if (validRole)
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Fail();
        }
         
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Then, in the Startup.ConfigureServices method, register the CustomUserEntityRoleHandler, and configure the policy.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

        services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            // Cookie settings
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

            options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Login/UserAccessDenied"; // change the path to yours.
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        });

        //register the CustomUserEntityRoleHandler
        services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, CustomUserEntityRoleHandler>();
        //configure the policy.
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AdminPolicy", policy =>
                policy.Requirements.Add(new CustomUserEntityRoleClaim("Admin")));
        }); 
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
    }
```

After that, in the controller, you could add the `[Authorize]` attribute with policy:

```
    [Authorize(Policy ="AdminPolicy")]
    public IActionResult Privacy()
    { 
        return View();
    }
```

The screenshot as below:

[image]

More detail information about creating Policy-Based authorization, check the following articles:

[Policy-based authorization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

[Policy-Based And Role-Based Authorization In ASP.NET Core 3.0 Using Custom Handler](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/policy-based-role-based-authorization-in-asp-net-core/)

**[Update]**

To add multiple roles for application and entity, you could try to change the CustomUserEntityRoleClaim class as below:

```
public class CustomUserEntityRoleClaim: IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public string ApplicationRoleName { get; }
    public string EntityRoleName { get; set; }
    public CustomUserEntityRoleClaim(string approleName, string entityroleName)
    {
        ApplicationRoleName = approleName;
        EntityRoleName = entityroleName;
    }
}
```

Then, refer the following code to configure the policy:

```
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AdminPolicy", policy =>
                policy.Requirements.Add(new CustomUserEntityRoleClaim("applicationRole", "entityrole")));
        });
```

And, in the CustomUserEntityRoleHandler's method, you could access the `ApplicationRoleName` property and the `EntityRoleName` property, then, query the database and check whether user have permission to access the resource.

Comment: If the role was for the entire application and not an entity in the application. The application itself has roles Such as Admin and User, but the role I would like to create a policy for is for groups/entities. Users will be able to create entities and those entities will have roles. Just like facebook has roles for the app facebook where zukerberg and team are admins and the rest are users, but users can also create groups and assign roles to them. A GroupId would have to be passed to the policy through the controller to validate the role, question is how do I pass that to the policy?

Comment: Hi @SmithWalikoMsiska, From your description, it seems that there have two kinds of roles, one for the entire application and one of the group/entities. If that is the case, please check the update in my reply, you could add a property in the CustomUserEntityRoleClaim class, then use it to transfer the data(groupid or entityid).